# how to detect peaks in a particular range in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series and I would like to detect (and identify them) some peaks but only for a particular range in R.

```
    here is an example
## generate test data with 3 peaks
set.seed(123)
x <- seq(0, 360, length = 20)
y <- abs(rnorm(20, mean = 1, sd = 0.1))
y[5:10] <- c(2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 2)
y <- c(y, 0.8 * y, 1.2 * y)
x <- seq(0, 360, along = y)
y[6] <- y[7]   # test case with 2 neighbouring equal points
plot(x, y, type="b")
```

#
In that example, let says, I want to select peaks (y) only between 6 and 9 (2 peaks) or only between 2 and 4 (also 2 peaks).

I am aware of several packages in R detecting peaks (e.g. Peaks, pastecs, quantmod, pracma, splus2R) but none seems to have this feature, usually only having a minimum threshold.

Any advice would be appreciated.

thank you

Martin

Edit: The code provided by Eric works perfectly. But with my own datasets I have a small problem. What would you do to detect only one peak if same values twice in a certain window (x). Basically I would like to create a conditional statement that would say, you need a certain number of points (x) between peaks to be considered as two distinctive peaks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to plot only those peaks? Or do you just want the values?

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate but am too lazy to find the match at the moment...

Comment: Look at the centwave stuff they use in the XCMS package. It does a wavelet transform of the signal to find peaks and works really well.
https://rdrr.io/bioc/xcms/man/findChromPeaks-centWave.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this gets close (not sure if you care about detecting the peak with two values twice).

```
# Reproduce your data
set.seed(123)
x <- seq(0, 360, length = 20)
y <- abs(rnorm(20, mean = 1, sd = 0.1))
y[5:10] <- c(2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 2)
y <- c(y, 0.8 * y, 1.2 * y)
x <- seq(0, 360, along = y)
y[6] <- y[7]   # test case with 2 neighbouring equal points
plot(x, y, type="b")

# shift y up and down a position (for peak identification)
yu <- c(tail(y, -1), NA)
yd <- c(NA, head(y, -1))

# identify peaks that are in the correct range 
# where y is higher than the point before and after
high <- which(y - yu >= 0 & y - yd >= 0 & y > 6 & y < 9)
low  <- which(y - yu >= 0 & y - yd >= 0 & y >= 2 & y <= 4) # one peak is at 4

# plot lines at peaks
abline(v = x[high], col = 'blue')
abline(v = x[low], col = 'red')
```

[image]